# Sails.js : redirection after http delete request

Tags: javascript, redirect, sails.js

I start with Sail.js and I don't understand redirection.
When I do a POST and use res.redirect("/articles/") I haven't any problem.

'post /article': 'ArticleController.create',

```
create: function (req, res) {
        if (!req.param('titre') || !req.param('resume') || !req.param('contenu')) {
        res.status(400);
        return res.json();
    }
    else {
        Article.create({
            titre: req.param('titre'),
            resume: req.param('resume'),
            contenu: req.param('contenu'),
            url: req.param('titre').replace(/ /g, "-")
        }).exec(function (err, post) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("erreur T_T");
                console.log(err);
                return res.json(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Article ajouté.");
                console.log(post);
                res.redirect("/articles/");

            }
        });
    }
}
```

But when it's a delete http request I have a "not found" response :

'delete /article': 'ArticleController.delete',

```
delete: function (req, res) {
        if (!req.param('id')) {
            res.status(400);
            return res.json();
        } else {
            Article.destroy({
                id: req.param('id')
            }).exec(function (err, article)
            {
                if (article.length == 0) {
                    console.log("L'article n'existe pas.");
                    console.log("ID = " + req.param('id'));
                    res.status(404);
                    return res.json();
                } else {
                    console.log("L'article a bien été supprimé");
                    console.log(article);
                    res.redirect("/articles/");
                }
            });
        }
    },
```

Thanks a lot.

---

Edit :

Article is not null :
[console.log(article);](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/845935Capture.png)

But my redirection doesn't work :
[res.redirect("/articles/");](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/933296Capture2.png)

---

Edit 2 : (more details)

```
console.log("L'article a bien été supprimé"); //OK
console.log(article); //OK
res.redirect("/articles/"); //Works in an other methode but not here
```

Comment: Are you sure article.length isn't 0?

Comment: I had a similar issue with action called new. Renamed it and it worked fine for some reason.
And doing res.locals.debug, did weird stuff as well, and it was again after res.locals.debug1. Sometimes its the variable name that matters. Sails issue I guess.

Comment: try checking for an error. like `if(err) {console.log(err);}` just in case

Comment: @thecodethinker  'if(err){console.log(err);}' : I haven't any error.

Comment: @MartinMalinda I renamed my delete methode to deletearticle and redirection 'res.redirect("/articles/");' does not work.

Comment: @dm_fr you should still check for errors. Just because your article is fine doesn't mean there aren't other errors. Try seeing if it will redirect to a different location

Comment: @thecodethinker Ok. I tried this : 'res.redirect("http://www.google.fr");' and google send me a 400 Bad request. Is res a delete request ? [my postman screen](http://s29.postimg.org/ef0zdixk7/Capture.png)

Comment: @dm_fr That's what I'm thinking. But then you're create method would redirect with a POST resquest

Comment: @thecodethinker But how to create a get request in this delete methode ? How to use a controller in an other controller ? I try : 'sails.controllers.controller_name.methode' but that doesn't work.

Comment: @dm_fr I'm not sure. Try asking on the sails IRC

Answer (score 0):

add your custom route to route.js

'/articles/delete/:id': ArticlesController.delete

I guess, before sails' blueprints do this automatically:
" Finally, all `actions` blueprints support an optional path           *

- parameter, `id`, for convenience.   "

but now, they remove it from the current documentation.